# SQL Count occurrences of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I want to count occurrences of Number 3 from multiple columns with group by Primary Key.
I have a table like this.

[image]

And I have tried with this.

[image]

But my output is

[image]

But expected output is something like this

[image]

Comment: post  code as text and not image  ...  so we can avoid of rewrite the code  ...

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Revise your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only counts rows with multiple threes one time.

You could use a union:

```
select  id
,       sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from    (
        select id, s1 as val from t1
        union all select id, s2 from t1
        union all select id, s3 from t1
        union all select id, s4 from t1
        union all select id, s5 from t1
        ) sub
group by
        id
```

[Example at db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vTFyRpETJrkRRywqfPxamN/3)

Comment: but this returns zero as null.is there any way to get them as zeros

Comment: Hmm, then you can't use `where` as that would filter out all rows. You could use a `sum` that only counts instances of `3`, updated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
select id,
  (s1 = 3) + (s2 = 3) + (s3 = 3) + (s4 = 3) + (s5 = 3) valcount
from tablename
```

Each of the boolean expressions:

```
s? = 3
```

evaluates to `0` or `1`.

Comment: Nice, no need for a union. This should work since the OP says ID is a primary key

Comment: Id is the primary key as I can see in the image. So there is no need for grouping

Comment: @AdaS . . . For this to have equivalent to your query, you should add `having valcount > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Query..

```
select id,(count(s1)+count(s2)+count(s3)+count(s4)+count(s5))valcount from(
select id, case when s1=3  then 1 end as s1, 
case when s2=3  then 1 end as s2,
case when s3=3  then 1 end as s3,
case when s4=3  then 1 end as s4,
case when s5=3  then 1 end as s5 
from test) group by id
```

and Try another way

```
select id,
count(decode(s1,3,1))+
count(decode(s2,3,1))+
count(decode(s3,3,1))+
count(decode(s4,3,1))+
count(decode(s5,3,1))valcount
from test
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,  ( SUM(CASE WHEN s1 =3 THEN  1 ELSE  0 END ) +    SUM(CASE WHEN s2 =3 THEN  1 ELSE  0 END ) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN s3 =3 THEN  1 ELSE  0 END ) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN s4 =3 THEN  1 ELSE  0 END ) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN s5 =3 THEN  1 ELSE  0 END )     ) AS val FROM t1 GROUP BY id
```

**I think it will be helpful for you**